# Merge dictionary with recurrence

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a loop:

```
all_rec = {}
for i in range(0, 2):
     rec = buildings[best_buildings[i]]['recommendations']
```

The value of 'rec' after first iteration:

```
rec = {'a': {'b': 2, 'c': 1}, 'd': {'e': 5}}
```

The value of 'rec' after second iteration:

```
rec = {'d': {'e': 4}}
```

The data type of 'recommendations' is a dictionary. How can I add all the 'rec' dictionaries resulting from this loop into one dictionary 'all_rec'?

I want 'all_rec' to look like this:

```
all_rec = {'a': {'b': 2, 'c': 1}, 'd': {'e': 5}, 'd': {'e': 4}}
```

Keeping both 'd': {'e': 5} and 'd': {'e': 4} in the new dictionary. How can I do that in Python 2.7?

Comment: You can't. Dictionaries in Python must have unique keys.

Comment: Make the values a `list` instead. Append to that list instead of overwriting.

Comment: collections.defaultdict IS the solution, but I need you data to write the code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to keep all such values, it suggests that the values in the lower dictionaries should be lists, at least for the summary list:

```
all_rec = {}
for i in range(0, 2):
     rec = buildings[best_buildings[i]]['recommendations']
     for dk, dc in rec.items():
         if dk not in all_rec:
             all_rec[dk] = {k:[v] for k,v in dc.items()}
         else:
             for k,v in dc.items():
                 if k in all_rec[dk]:
                     all_rec[dk][k].append(v)
                 else:
                     all_rec[dk][k] = [v]

print(all_rec)
```

```
{'a': {'b': [2], 'c': [1]}, 'd': {'e': [5,4]}}
```

This is Python 3.7; I don't know how you'd need to adjust to use 2.7 but I kept it as basic as possible.

Comment: range works in Python2.7 - the different is that i Python 2 range() produces a list.

Comment: @TonySuffolk66 I thought it was just `xrange` - my mistake. I haven't used Python 2.x but all the code I've seen used `xrange`.

Comment: xrange would have been a better thing to use here - but in Python 2 range would be correct (but less efficient).

Answer (score 0):

I do not have your data but this is the rough idea:

**If you want to sum the recommentations:**

```
from collections import defaultdict

all_rec = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))
for i in range(0, 2):
     rec[buildings[best_buildings[i]]] += buildings[best_buildings[i]]['recommendations']
```

**If you want to append the recommendations:**

```
from collections import defaultdict

all_rec = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))
for i in range(0, 2):
     rec[buildings[best_buildings[i]]].append(buildings[best_buildings[i]]['recommendations'])
```

**---
DEMO**

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> 
>>> demo = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))
>>> demo['a']['b'] += 1
>>> demo
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x7f931a2d2700>, {'a': defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'b': 1})})
>>> demo['a']['b'] += 1
>>> demo
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x7f931a2d2700>, {'a': defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'b': 2})})
>>> 
>>> demo = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))
>>> demo['a']['b'].append(1)
>>> demo
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x7f931a2d2b80>, {'a': defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'b': [1]})})
>>> demo['a']['b'].append(1)
>>> demo
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x7f931a2d2b80>, {'a': defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'b': [1, 1]})})
>>>
```